# Why I keep getting posts.ID unknown column while the column exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my WooCommerce SQL query below. I keep getting the error,

```
Unknown column 'posts.ID' is 'on clause'
```

but my posts.ID column does exist.

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.ID as product_id, posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM wp_posts posts, 
wp_terms terms, wp_term_relationships term_relationships LEFT JOIN wp_wc_product_meta_lookup 
wc_product_meta_lookup ON posts.ID=wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id WHERE 
posts.ID=term_relationships.object_id AND term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id=terms.term_id 
AND terms.name!='exclude-from-catalog' AND posts.post_type IN ('product') 
AND (  ( ( posts.post_title LIKE '%bruno%') OR ( posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%bruno%') 
OR ( posts.post_content LIKE '%bruno%' ) OR ( wc_product_meta_lookup.sku LIKE '%bruno%' ) )) 
AND posts.post_status IN ('publish') ORDER BY posts.post_parent ASC, posts.post_title ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

So, write the query correctly as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID as product_id, p.post_parent as parent_id
FROM wp_posts p JOIN
     wp_term_relationships
     ON p.id = tr.object_id JOIN
     wp_terms t
     ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id LEFT JOIN
     wp_wc_product_meta_lookup pml
     ON p.ID = pml.product_id
WHERE t.name <> 'exclude-from-catalog' AND
      p.post_type IN ('product') AND 
      (p.post_title LIKE '%bruno%' OR
       p.post_excerpt LIKE '%bruno%' OR
       p.post_content LIKE '%bruno%'  OR 
       pml.sku LIKE '%bruno%'
      ) AND
      p.post_status IN ('publish')
ORDER BY p.post_parent ASC, p.post_title ASC;
```

Notes:

- The specific problem is that `,` affects the scoping of identifiers.  You cannot reference a table alias from before the comma in an `ON` clause after the comma.
- I see no reason to duplicate table names.
- Using table aliases is good, but the query is simpler if the aliases are shorter.